# What is the time complexity of the algorithm provided?

Tags: algorithm, math, time-complexity, data-science, big-o

Consider the following c++ code of a function:

```
A(int n)
{
​ i = 1;
 S = 1;
 while (S<=n)
​ {
 ​ i++;
 ​ S = S + i;
 ​ printf("Edward");
​ }
​ }
```

Suppose the function is fed with n = k, then what is the time complexity of this code?
Answer is O(square root of n).

Comment: What is your question? As you wrote, the answer is O(sqrt(n)).

Comment: find the time complexity of this code and I provided the answer.

Comment: Why are you asking if you already know the answer?

Comment: I want to know the concept and that's more important than the answer.

Comment: In that case you should state clearly what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

In each iteration, `i` will be added to the previous accumulated value and `i` will be increased one unit. Hence, `S = 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + k`. Here `k` is the number of loop iterations which is the time complexity of the code.
As this sum is equal to `k(k+1)/2`, we should find `k` such that `n = k(k+1)/2`. Therefore, `k = Theta(sqrt(n))`.

Comment: Why k is the time complexity of the code as time complexity is the number of times a statement is executed and in the for loop, we've statements inside of the loop and they too have to be counted for time complexity.

Comment: @SachinSharma Because `k` is the value of `i` in the `k`th iteration. On the other hand, `S‌ <= n`.